# android add item to arraylist from arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a gridview that filled using a custom adapter in an activity, and I want you to press a target item in another activity in another gridview.

```
private static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item("Restaurante Arsenal", R.drawable.arsenal));

        items.add(new Item("Restaurante The Grill", R.drawable.grill));
        items.add(new Item("Rte Las Delicias", R.drawable.delicias));
        items.add(new Item("Restaurante Europa", R.drawable.logo_restaurante_europa));


        items.add(new Item("Restaurante Coconut", R.drawable.coco));
        items.add(new Item("Rte GastroXabia", R.drawable.gastroxabia));
    }
```

I had planned to use this:

```
  MisLocalesFavActivity.MyAdapter.items.add(MyAdapter.items.get(position));
```

So:

```
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String[] opc = new String[] { "Añadir a mis locales favoritos", "Copiar", "Eliminar"};



            AlertDialog opciones = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Restaurantes_Activity.this)
            .setTitle("Opciones")
            .setItems(opc,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int selected) {
                    if (selected == 0) {
                        //acciones para editar


                        MisLocalesFavActivity.MyAdapter.items.add(MyAdapter.items.get(position));   





                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Añadido a mis locales favoritos! " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (selected == 1) {
                        //acciones para copiar
                    }else if (selected == 2) {
                        //acciones para eliminar
                    }
                }
            }).create();
            opciones.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

But I have an error in .add

Specifically this:
    The method add(MisLocalesFavActivity.MyAdapter.Item) in the type      List is not applicable for the arguments

(Restaurantes_Activity.MyAdapter.Item)

THANKS !!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this,

```
public MyAdapter(Context context)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // Add this if condition in your code
    if(items != null && items.size() != 0) {
       items.clear();
    }
    items.add(new Item("Restaurante Arsenal", R.drawable.arsenal));

    items.add(new Item("Restaurante The Grill", R.drawable.grill));
    items.add(new Item("Rte Las Delicias", R.drawable.delicias));
    items.add(new Item("Restaurante Europa", R.drawable.logo_restaurante_europa));


    items.add(new Item("Restaurante Coconut", R.drawable.coco));
    items.add(new Item("Rte GastroXabia", R.drawable.gastroxabia));
}
```

Don't use like this:

MisLocalesFavActivity.MyAdapter.items.add(MyAdapter.items.get(position));

If you want to pick FoodItem at particular position in onItemLongClick then you use as follows :

```
if (selected == 0 && position >= 0 && position < items.size()) {

  FoodItem itemObj = items.get(position);
  // Do whatever you want ....
 }
```

and also change the model name "Item" to "FoodItem", it will work for you. I hope it will be very useful..........

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work, follow the error. Add

Answer (score 0):

don't use `static` for `items`. defined a method in MyAdapter to add item. 
this is my code to solve your problem.

MyAdapter

```
public void addItem(Item item){items.add(item);}
```

OverWirte `getItem(int position)` `return items.get(position)`

in method `onItemLongClick`

```
adapter.additem(adapter.getItem(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to centralize the Arraylists in application class. It will help you more.

Comment: check this answer, you will get an idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093997/android-quiz-score-point/22095806#22095806