# Android quiz score point

Tags: android, android-activity, increment

I have sought for this for a long time with no chance, I will now have the permission to ask this question.

I am trying to developing a quiz in Android whereas I have a problem when updating the score. At the moment, I have two classes; MainActivity and Question002 (and in MainActivity there is the first question).

In my MainActivity I have an int called currentPoint. I have created four buttons and by clicking on the right button, there is an increment (currentPoint++). Then in class Question002, I have the following code:

```
    MainActivity a = new MainActivity();
```

Upon answering correct I've said:

```
    a.currentPoint++;
```

However, this returns its' first value meaning the initialization (which is by standard 0) instead of 1, if the first question is correctly answered. How do I pass the value 1 to my Question002 class, when the first question is answered correctly and it shows the next activity (thus next class)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Create an Application Class

```
class MyApplication extends Application{
 public int currentScore;
 private SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    sp = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
            MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentScore = sp.getInt("score",0);

}

    public void updateScore(int increment)
    {
       currentScore = currentScore+increment;
       sp.edit().putInt("score", currentScore).commit();
    }
 }
```

Now On MainActivity add the following code -

```
 class MainActivity extends Activity{
 public MyApplication application;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0)
    {
       application = (MyApplication) getApplication();

        // to get current score 
       int currentScore = application.currentScore;
       // to update currentScore
        application.updateScore(1);
    }
 }
```

Same On 
Now On Question002 add the following code -

```
 class Question002 extends Activity{
 public MyApplication application;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0)
    {
       application = (MyApplication) getApplication();

        // to get current score 
       int currentScore = application.currentScore;
       // to update currentScore
        application.updateScore(1);
    }
 }
```

now finaly in the add android:name property to the application tag -

> ```
>   <application
>     android:name="yourpackagename.MyApplication"
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
> ```

Your score is stored in MyApplication class. All the Activity can access it by via getApplication() method after onCreate() has called. 
No need to pass score via intent.
Score also saved in sharedprefernce and loaded from it too.

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort. Now that part works, but another problem arised. It permanently stores my point, so even when I close the app and open it to play the game, my point continues from my games before, while it has to be reset to 0 again on app-close. How do I fix this?

Comment: ok, then just remove onCreate() and  private SharedPreferences sp from MyApplication class . Chage updateScore to this -
    public void updateScore(int increment)
    {
       currentScore = currentScore+increment;
    }

Comment: If this answer solve your problem, would you mark it as right answer ?

Comment: I will try it out as soon as possible. Thanks for your help. If it solves, of course I will mark, else wise I will probably ask again :)

Comment: It went back to 0, but now it is increasing again, so the problem is still there. When I re-open the app, the int value does not start from 0 :(

Comment: ok, change android:allowBackup="false" on application tag in manifest.

Comment: That did not help either I am sorry that I am taking your time. And thanks for your efforts. What can the solution now be?

Comment: when you are reopening the app then I think its starting from last activity you opened , am I right ? if yes then why you want to decrease score . Or if it is starting from MainActivity (assuming MainActivity is your home screen) , then just add this line in
onStart(){
application.currentScore=0;
}

Comment: It starts at MainActivity, so that the player has to start over again to avoid any kind of cheat (such as going back to previous questions). I will try that you have written

Comment: When I create the onStart method in MainActivity and writing that inside, then the app won't even start. Do I have to write something else in that method?

Comment: call super.onStart(); inside onStart();
like this -
onStart(){
super.onStart();
application.currentScore=0; 
}

Comment: Thanks! Now it is solved! You will have the mark now!

Comment: turn it on . android:allowBackup="true"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sharedpreference` to maintain score but if you want to use main activity , then declare currentpoint as `public static variable` and then increment it like

> `MainActivity.currentPoint++;`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(your answer correct)
{
currentPoint = currentPoint+1;

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Question002.class);
myIntent.putExtra("result", currentPoint );
startActivity(myIntent);


}
```

In class `Question002`

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("result", 0);
```